# Keep boolean toggle state on navigation in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a checkbox that toggles an image in a list in angularjs. The toggle shows images when clicked. However when i navigate to other views and then return to the list view the toggle state for the images is unchecked.

**List view checkbox**

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-click="vm.toggleImage()">
```

**List**

```
<td ng-if="vm.showImage">    
<img ng-src="{{task.imageUrl}}" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-circle" />
</td>
```

**Controller**

```
  // Show Image
  vm.showImage = false;
  vm.toggleImage = function () {
        //Inverse Boolean 
        vm.showImage = !vm.showImage;
   }
```

There are no page refreshes during the navigation.

How do i keep the images showing as the user navigates back and forth through the SPA?

Comment: The only way would be either to implement a global controller which holds the $scope.vm variable(s), or event a service.

Comment: Your controller explicitly resets `vm.showImage` to `false`.  If you want ayour data to persist and/or be shared between controllers it needs to be added to a `$scope`.

Comment: @PM77-1 So would i need to add it the main app.js $scope

Comment: You may do that and then inject the scope into your controller.

Comment: Have you tried using a factory or service to "own" your vm variable?

Comment: @brcpar I have not. I am still learning angular. have only just touched on factories. I made one for my $resource. Ill give that a go . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to keep your state/model in a service.

then you can inject it where you need it like this:

```
ItemController.$inject = ['Items'];
function ItemController (Items) {
   var vm = this;
   vm.items = Items;
}
```

a service is a singelon. That's a fancy way to say, its an object that gets retained during the entire time the program is active.

The item service can look something like this:

```
function Items () {
  return [
     {name: 'test1', on:true},
     {name: 'test2', on:true},
     {name: 'test3', on:false},
     {name: 'test4', on:true},
     {name: 'test5', on:false},
     ];
}
```

You can see this in action in the [following plunk](http://goo.gl/YgO7aH)
you can click on any of the items and change their on/off state. then click the
log on button to trigger another route, there is a link in there that will take you back.
the state will stay the same, while the controller will be recreated.

Don't hesitate to ask if you have further questions about this!

Comment: Yip .. thats perfect , thank you. Just a bit off topic => What is that cloak style in the head?

Comment: @gerdi that's a way to prevent showing the template before it's ready. It makes sure the users doesn't see {{ myVariable }} on its screen.